# Cannot print a sentence including space with libcurses

Tags: c, curses

```
#include <curses.h>

int main(){
  initscr();
  refresh();
  
  char s[25]; 
  mvprintw(1,0,"Enter sentence: ");
  refresh();
  
  scanw("%s", s); // Input `one two`.
  mvprintw(2,0,"%s\n", s); // This just prints `one`.
  refresh();
  
  getch();
  endwin();
  return 0;
}
```

Input is `one two`.

Output is just `one`, second half is missing.

Does `scanw` not treat spaces properly?

Comment: "*Does scanw not treat spaces properly?*". It's working as designed. The specifiers mean the same as they do for `scanf`.  From the [scanf manual](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) regarding `%s`: "Matches a sequence of non-white-space characters". That is, it stops matching on the first white space. So working exactly as intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scan` functions generally breaks at whitespaces, so instead of

```
scanw("%s", s);
```

do

```
scanw("%24[^\n]", s); // always do bounds checking
```

That is, read at most 24 non-newlines.

And, you should always check that the extraction works:

```
if(scanw("%24[^\n]", s) == 1) { ... }
```

If you mix input from here and there, consider using the "greedy" version that "eats" leftovers:

```
scanw(" %24[^\n]", s)    // note the space at the beginning
```

Comment: Your last character (the 25th one) would be the null terminating character correct?

Comment: @Dan Yes, and this works as expected _if_ the check (`if(... == 1`) is added.

Comment: doc says `returns ERR on failure and an integer equal to the number of fields scanned on success`, so `==1` check is if 1 field (or character) is scanned?

Comment: @Dan Yes, exactly that. If you do 2 scans, like `scanw("%d %d", &first_int, &second_int)`, the comparison would be `== 2`